# Failure Delivering Result on onActivityResult method

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult

Currently trying to call another app from main app, here are short diagram :

`App A` -> Send Task Code to App B -> `App B` (Do some task) 
`App B` -> (return back result to App A) -> `App A`

Here how App A call App B and send Task Code :

```
private void attemptFacialRecognition(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.yai.facerecognitionapp.FACIAL_RECOGNITION");

    if(intent != null){
        // We found the activity
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

        // 0x10000000 = login
        intent.putExtra(FLAG_ACVITY_TASK, FLAG_ACTIVITY_LOGIN);
        LoginActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent, FLAG_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

Here are manifest on App B :

```
<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.yai.facerecognitionapp.FaceRecognitionAppActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.yai.facerecognitionapp.FACIAL_RECOGNITION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here App B returning back result to App A :

```
private void resultActivity(boolean result){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(FLAG_ACVITY_RESULT, result);
    intent.putExtra(FLAG_ACVITY_TASK, TASK);

    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

    finish();
}
```

And here are how App A get Result from App B :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == FLAG_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        Log.e("xxx", " " + requestCode + " " + resultCode);

        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
        if(bundle != null){
            Boolean res = data.getBooleanExtra(FLAG_ACVITY_RESULT, false);
            Log.e("XXX", res);
        }
```

Every time try to get `getStringExtra`, it returning `Null Pointer Exception`.
Here are the log cat :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.yai.xdbg, PID: 32202
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=777, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.yai.xdbg/com.yai.xdbg.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3646)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3689)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:947)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
  at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:232)
  at com.yai.xdbg.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(LoginActivity.java:162)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6226)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3642)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3689) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)
```

What i missed out? I cannot figure it out and many read from SO and no one doesn't works. Have tried different way and still stuck on this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: `intent.putExtra(FLAG_ACVITY_RESULT, result);` – `result` is a `boolean`, but you're trying to retrieve it as a `String` - `data.getStringExtra(FLAG_ACVITY_RESULT)` - so that returns null, and `Log` doesn't like nulls.

Comment: @MikeM. Question edited

Comment: You need to post the _actual_ updated code, along with the new stack trace. There is no `Intent#getBooleanExtra()` that takes only a `String`, and the correct method cannot return null.

Comment: There is no `Log.e()` method that takes a `Boolean` as the second argument.